# Validate at least one checkbox is ticked in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to do a server side validation in Rails 5 and I am having issues. I'm still very much a noob but this has me stumped.

I want to check to see if any of the 4 checkbox options have been ticked on saving.

In my form I have:

`<%= f.input :property_type, label: 'List as', as: :check_boxes, collection: %w(Student Graduate Professional Family), checked: property.property_type %>`

And I have tried

`validates :property_type, acceptance: { message: 'must be selected' }` and `validates :property_type, presence: true`  neither have worked.

I've also tried to create a custom validation but I could not get that to work either.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: It might be easier to use [`collection_check_boxes`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) Aside from that, the best way to validate the data may depend on how you are storing it. What data type is the `:property_type` column? `array`, `jsonb`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Custom validation should work in your case. could you please check with below snippet?

```
  validates : property_type_is_selected

  private

  def property_type_is_selected
    if self.property_type.blank?
      self.errors.add(:property_type, 'must be selected.')
    end
  end
```